# PHP not displaying errors on debian

Tags: php, apache, debian

I have PHP installed on debian with apache web server. For some reason even with display_errors() turned on, error_reporting(E_ALL), and display_startup_errors() on, it still doesn't display errors. But if there is no error PHP works, otherwise I see only a blank white screen. The errors are getting logged in the error log and everything. On my windows setup I haven't had this problem, so maybe it is debian? If anyone has any experience or tips please let me know.

Comment: do a `php_info()` at a place where you KNOW the error is occuring, and compare the global and local values of the various error settings. if they're not what you expected, then the .ini changes you've made are not being applied, or are being overriden somewhere.